# postgres function with insert cast datatypes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE api.newtable (
    check_date timestamp NULL,
    filename text NULL,
    mysum numeric NULL
);
```

I want to insert data over an api. this works techniqualy.
But in detail it doesn't.

This is my function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.test_newtable( spec jsonb)
     RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
begin
  --Consider all columns in specialist table as character varying and code column as integer.
  INSERT INTO api.newtable  (                               
                                        check_date,
                                        filename,
                                        mysum 
                                    )
  select 
            j.spec->>'crawldate'::timestamp,
         j.spec->>'filename',
         j.spec->>'mysum'::numeric
         
  from jsonb_array_elements(spec) as j(spec);
end;
$BODY$;
```

And this is my SQL for adding data:

```
SELECT api.test_newtable('[
                              {
                                "crawldate":"14-07-2022",
                               "filename":"tesjjjt",
                                "mysum": "1"
                            }
                            ]'::jsonb);
```

If I just add text data like filename or others it works. But the cast of other types doesn't work.
How do I have to cast?

Comment: numbers work too, the rest you have to encode base64

Comment: and converting to Timestamp is also not good, you could let the string stay

Comment: Do `(j.spec->>'crawldate'):;timestamp` and `(j.spec->>'mysum')::numeric`. Otherwise you are applying the cast to the object key name not the value returned.

Comment: I should have added that it would be alright to leave them as text for the `INSERT`  as Postgres will do an implicit cast to the field data type. The only issue might be with the date/month order of the timestamp string. When I  tried it here I got an error as my `DateStyle=ISO, MDY` and the date is `DMY`.